# Local Server Vs. Production Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, ado.net

Im kinda going a little crazy here. I moved my web application to a server and im getting this error below, but on my localhost it works great. Im kinda at a loss of what i should try. Any help would be very much appreciated. Im finding that the error has to have something to do with the dataset not pulling back any data, when I do a for each statement. But the weird thing is that I do a for each statement on another page and it works fine. Here is my for each statement, that im assuming doesnt work. The reason im assuming it b/c when i test it on local it works fine:

```
Dim retObj As New ClassLibrary1.sql_class

 For Each row As DataRow In retObj.sel_all_email_list(company).tables(0).rows
    email += row("EMAIL_ADDRESS") & "/"
 Next
```

'*****************************************************
   sql_class

```
query = "SELECT * " _
           & " FROM EMAIL_LIST " _
           & " WHERE UCASE(COMPANY) = '" & company & "'"

 Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(query, myConnection)
 Dim ds As New DataSet

        Try
            myConnection.Open()
            adapter2.Fill(ds, "test_table")

        *returns the dataset, didnt want to type all of the code

        Catch ex As Exception

        Finally
            myConnection.Close()
        End Try  

'*****************************************************
Error:
Exception Details: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Cannot find table 0.
```

Comment: Without the code context, the exception message is useless.

Comment: There is not enough context to even begin to speculate

Comment: Did you change your connection string?

Answer (score 1):

Check the SQL DB running in Production.

The SQL statement used to fill the Dataset isn't returning any data. That leads to the Dataset not having any tables.

As a result when you make your call to `Dataset.Tables(0)` a `System.IndexOutOfRangeException` gets thrown (as there are no tables in the Tables collection).

You can mitigate against this by calling `Dataset.Tables.Count` to ensure it has items before attempting to access the collection.

```
If retObj.sel_all_email_list(company).tables.count > 0 Then
'Do something
End If
```